# Не отображается прогресс бар C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Сегодня столкнулся с проблемой. Почему когда по нажатию кнопки `progressbar1.visible = true;` прогресс бар всерано не отображается? Видемых причин на то нет. В чём тогда дело? 
Код:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string desk = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(desk+"/MyWPI Downloads/"+"aimp.exe")) //если файл существует - открыть его
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(desk + "/MyWPI Downloads/" + "aimp.exe");
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            label1.Visible = true;

            Directory.CreateDirectory(desk + "/" + "MyWPI Downloads"); //создать директорию если её нет

            string link = @"https://www.aimp.ru/?do=download.file&id=4"; //ссылка
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(link), desk + "/MyWPI Downloads/" + "aimp.exe"); //сохранение файла
        }



    }

    private void webClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = false; //если загрузка завершена,  скрыть label и progressbar и открыть файл
        label1.Visible = false;
        string desk = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(desk + "/MyWPI Downloads/" + "aimp.exe");
    }

    private void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //если прогресс изменён
        progressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive / 100; //Максимальное значение прогресс бара исходя из размера файла в Байтах
        progressBar1.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived / 100; // при каждом новом загруженом Байте прибавить значение прогресс бара 
    }
```

Comment: Это потому, что в момент работы `webClient` по скачиванию файла он работает в потоке (нитке исполнения) в которой работает визуальный интерфейс, что заставляет последний подвиснуть и не показать прогрессбар.

Comment: И как это исправить? Дело в том что до этого прогресс бар отображался.

Comment: Нужно использовать асинхронность. Посмотрите хотя бы этот [пример](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/WindowsFormsDownloadFile) небольшой программки.